# Fixed fairshare in YARN Fair Scheduler

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In YARN 2.7.3, "fixed fairshare" is not documented but implemented in [ComputeFairShares.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fair/policies/ComputeFairShares.java). Copied function signature below for convenience.

Use one example here to illustrate my understanding of "fixed fairshare": if ABC queue is define with "minResoures == 100; maxResoures == 100; weight == 0", we will have a fixed queue allocated 100 memory, not participating in instantanous fairshare (IFS); that is, (1) even when ABC queue is empty, its share of 100 memory will not be allocated to other active queue thru IFS; and (2) when ABC queue is not empty, it will not grab IFS shares from other empty queues.

Can YARN Fair Scheduler experts help confirm?

Function signature copied from ComputeFairShares.java:

```
/**
* Helper method to handle Schedulabes with fixed fairshares.
* Returns the resources taken by fixed fairshare schedulables,
* and adds the remaining to the passed nonFixedSchedulables.
*/
private static int handleFixedFairShares(
  Collection<? extends Schedulable> schedulables,
  Collection<Schedulable> nonFixedSchedulables,
  boolean isSteadyShare, ResourceType type) {


/**
 * Get the fairshare for the {@link Schedulable} if it is fixed, -1 
   otherwise
 *
 * The fairshare is fixed if either the maxShare is 0, weight is 0,
 * or the Schedulable is not active for instantaneous fairshare.
 */
 private static int getFairShareIfFixed(Schedulable sched,
   boolean isSteadyShare, ResourceType type) {
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]! Nice question imo!